# Compile FFMPEG RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, debian-buster

I'm trying to use RTMP protocol on homebridge server (Debian 10). I am following this tutorial:
https://sunoo.github.io/homebridge-camera-ffmpeg/configs/Reolink-camera.html 
But when I tried to install `libmp3lmae-dev` I've got this error:

```
libmp3lame-dev : Depend: libmp3lame0 (= 1:3.100-dmo2) but 3.100-2+b1 must be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its asking you to downgrade some of your packages. Try to install via Aptidude,
First install Aptitude: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
Then install your package as so: `sudo aptitude install libmp3lmae-dev`

It will automatically attempt to resolve your problem. You'll have to press `N` when it says `Not Installed` and `Y` when it asks you to downgrade.